# How to serve react app on server with sub-directory homepage on an existing domain?

Tags: reactjs, build, web-deployment

I am new to webdev. I want to deploy a react-app on our lab's server. i want other lab members to access this app with `https://ourlab.org:PORT_NUM/myApp`

On the lab server by sshing to it: under my home directory, i have this myApp folder. I give package.json this `"homepage":"https://ourlab.org/myApp"` field and then run `npm run build`, and then run `npx serve -s build`

it gives me

|   Serving!                                         │

│   - Local:            http://localhost:5000        │

│   - On Your Network:  http://159.89.xxx.xxx:5000   |

I expect I could access the app at url `https://ourlab.org:5000/myApp` on my local computer. But my browser does not get response.

BTW could someone please explain how this "homepage" works with more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run `serve`, you are serving the app from your local computer.
If you want to serve the app from your lab-server find the document root on that server, create there a directory "myApp" and copy the content of the build directory from your computer into that directory on your lab server.

The build directory is the result of running ´npm run build´ assuming you have created your app with create-react-app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Sorry I did not describe the problem very clearly but I am running the "serve -s build" command on the lab-server by sshing to it.

Comment: Then you ought to be able to reach it per http as http://159.89.xx.xx:5000.

Note: serve is not serving per https, only http.

Note 2: serve serves per default /index.html, so your route /myApp doesn‘t match.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Finally figured out this to be a port firewall issue haha. I am so dumb.